# calling different functions in the same javascript event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a table which contains dropdown lists in one column and when you select a number it gets multiplied by price and saves the answer in another cell. there are 4 columns and I want to calculate the total and save in another table while the values in the other 4 cells change. can I call the function which does this with onChange in the dropdownlist (onChange has been already assigned with another function return value too)

Comment: Can you like to a jsfiddle with an example? You can call as many functions as you want from the inside of your event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call. But as you said the other function is also an event handler it will be expecting an event as an argument when you call that function. So in your function definition check if the event is undefined before accessing it.

For eg:

```
function func1(KeyboardEvent e) {
    if (typeof(e) != 'undefined') { 
        ....
    }
}
```